# Facebook scrape blank page

Tags: facebook, dns, hosting, virtualhost, plesk

I am having problems with the Facebook open graph sharing API. I have noticed that when I select a page and use Facebook's sharing debugger tool, the scrape view a blank page. When I use the object debugger I noticed that I get the following error

> Curl Error : SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL: certificate subject name 'Plesk' does not match target host name 'website.com'

- If I look up the IP address for my website and enter it into the url I am greeted with the default plesk page.
- If I look up the default certificate in plesk, the domain name is set to Plesk
- Currently, I am using Lets Encrypt to create the certificate for the website
- I have more than one website on the server which is a dedicated server (I am not familiar with servers)

From the looks of it, I believe Facebook is scraping the IP of the website which is the default Plesk page and rendering no results

Comment: In plesk Go to Websites & Domains -> Webspaces -> select website -> toggle on the IPv6 address

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it normally:

Create a button or anchor with the following link (i.ex.). Be sure you put the correct "u" parameter in the link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.kloeckner.com/de/strategie.html" target="_blank" class="icon icon-facebook"></a>
```

Be sure you provide all Open Graph data meta tags in your current page you want to share:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="„Kl&ouml;ckner &amp; Co 2020“ – unsere Strategie | Kl&ouml;ckner &amp; Co SE" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kloeckner.com/de/strategie.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kloeckner.com/de/img/Konzern_Header_mobile.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Durch h&ouml;herwertige Produkte und Services sowie Digitalisierung der Liefer- und Leistungskette wollen wir die Ertragskraft von Kl&ouml;ckner &amp; Co steigern." />
```

Check with OpenGraphDebugger if all is provided fine:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kloeckner.com%2Fde%2Fstrategie.html

At least the debugger tries to resolve the webserver for your u-parmeter entered url. If there are problems during resolving, double check your dns A-records and AAAA-records vs. the IP-settings in your plesk subscription (sounds like you don´t use the DNS-settings outa plesk itself)

If you still get stucked, please provide us an url that we can crosscheck your problem.

kind regards
Michael